# Primefaces DataTable i can't delete a row when i add requiered to my input

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

i'm using JSF 2.8 and primefaces 6.0 i have a datatable with 2 actions update and delete. and i have a popup which contains a form with required fields displayed by clicking  on the create button.

but when i click on the button delete on datatable the line is not deleted and and a message appears that contains the attributes (of the popup) should'nt be null.

But when i remove required  from inputs it works.

While it's an action to delete the line has nothing to do with my form.

Here is my XHTML

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

<ui:define name="title">Test</ui:define>

<ui:define name="content">
<h:form id="form">

    <div class="ui-g">
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <div class="card card-w-title">     
            <h1>Ressource</h1>      

            <p:commandButton update=":form:nouvelleRessource"  value="Create" oncomplete="PF('createDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-add" title="Create"/>
            <p:commandButton  value="Import"  icon="ui-icon-import-export" title="Create"/>


                    <p:dataTable var="ressource" value="#{ressourceBean.ressources}"  paginator="true" rows="5" selectionMode="single" reflow="true"
                                    rowKey="#{ressource.idt_ressource}"  id="ut"  editable="true"  emptyMessage="Aucune ressource trouvée">
                               <f:facet name="header">
                                 Listes des ressources
                               </f:facet>

                           <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{ressourceBean.onEdit}"   />
                           <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{ressourceBean.onCancel}"  />


                            <p:column headerText="Id"  filterBy="#{ressource.idt_ressource}" filterMatchMode="contains" filterOptions="">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{ressource.idt_ressource}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText value="#{ressource.idt_ressource}" style="width:100%" />
                            </f:facet>
                             </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Nom"   filterBy="#{ressource.nom}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{ressource.nom}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText value="#{ressource.nom}" style="width:100%" />
                            </f:facet>
                             </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                             <p:column headerText="prenom"  filterBy="#{ressource.prenom}" filterMatchMode="contains"  >
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{ressource.prenom}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText value="#{ressource.prenom}" style="width:100%" />
                            </f:facet>
                             </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Matricule"  filterBy="#{ressource.matricule}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{ressource.matricule}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText value="#{ressource.matricule}" style="width:100%" />
                            </f:facet>
                             </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Mail"  filterBy="#{ressource.mail}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                            <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{ressource.mail}"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                            <h:inputText value="#{ressource.mail}" style="width:100%" />
                            </f:facet>
                             </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column   headerText="Modifier" >
                            <p:rowEditor/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column   headerText="Supprimer" >
                            <center>
                            <p:commandButton action="#{ressourceBean.delete(ressource)}" icon="ui-icon-delete" update="@ut" ajax="false"/>
                            </center>
                            </p:column>

                          </p:dataTable>


            <p:dialog header="Nouvelle ressource" widgetVar="createDialog" modal="true">

                    <p:panel id="nouvelleRessource" header="Create Ressource">
                    <p:panelGrid  columns="4"  columnClasses="ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4,ui-grid-col-2,ui-grid-col-4" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" style="border:0px none; background-color:transparent;">

                    <p:outputLabel for="nom1" value="Nom"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:inputText id="nom1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.nom}" required="true" />
                    <p:message for="nom1" display="icon" />
                    <label>nom</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="mail1" value="Mail"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:inputText id="mail1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.mail}"        
                                 requiredMessage="Please enter your email address."
                                 validatorMessage="Invalid email format"
                                 required="true">
                    <f:validateRegex
                        pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\+]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <label>Mail</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="prenom1" value="Prenom"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:inputText id="prenom1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.prenom}" required="true" />
                    <p:message for="prenom1" display="icon" />
                    <label>prenon</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="telephone1" value="Telephone"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:inputText id="telephone1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.telephone}" required="true" />
                    <p:message for="telephone1" display="icon" />
                    <label>Telephone</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="matricule1" value="Matricule"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:inputText id="matricule1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.matricule}" required="true"/>
                    <p:message for="matricule1" display="icon" />
                    <label>Matricule</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <p:outputLabel for="date1" value="Date d'entree"/>
                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield">
                    <p:calendar id="date1" value="#{ressourceBean.ressource1.dateEntree}" required="true"/>
                    <p:message for="date1" display="icon" />
                    <label>Matricule</label>
                    </h:panelGroup>


                    </p:panelGrid>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-save"  actionListener="#{ressourceBean.save}" onclick="PF('createDialog').hide()"  value="Save" update="ut" ajax="false" style="display:inline-block;margin-top:5px"/>
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-cancel" update="ut" onclick="PF('createDialog').hide()" value="Cancel" />
                </p:panel>
            </p:dialog>


            <p:commandButton update=":form:nouvelleRessource"  value="Create" oncomplete="PF('createDialog').show()" icon="ui-icon-add" title="Create"/>
            <p:commandButton  value="Import"  icon="ui-icon-import-export" title="Create"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `immediate="true"` to the delete button?

Comment: @OuerghiYassine thank u for u response immediate="true" works. but when i click on the button create my form appears with red lines, as if it applies the validation before the submission

Comment: I dont think that should happen, then try with: `<p:commandButton action="#{ressourceBean.delete(ressource)}" icon="ui-icon-delete" update="@ut" ajax="false">
 <p:ajax />
</p:commandButton>`

Comment: please add your `ressourceBean` to the question

Answer (score 2):

Use the  process attribute:

```
<p:ajax process="@form" update="...>
```

Because the `<p:ajax process>` and `<f:ajax execute>` defaults to `@this` and the modifications won't be executed.

Comment: Thanks u for the respose so i will use <P: ajax ...> instead of button delete ?